# Ansible - only run a series of tasks if a precondition is met

Tags: ansible

I have a package I need to install from a remote URL as in:

```
- get-url: url=http://foo.com/foo.deb dest=/tmp

- command: dpkg --skip-same-version -i /tmp/foo.deb

- apt: update_cache=yes

- apt: pkg=foo state=present
```

I'd only like to run the first 3 if pkg=foo isn't already present. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: But if the package is already present, nothing bad will happen. If you keep that `.deb` in your temp after download `get_url` is by default smart enough not to re-download it again.

Answer (score 8):

You have to [register a variable with the result](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_variables.html#filters-often-used-with-conditionals), and then use [when statement](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_conditionals.html).

```
tasks:
  - shell: /usr/bin/foo
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True

  - debug: msg="it failed"
    when: result|failed
```

Comment: Thanks! I take it I'd then have to add the same when to the first 3 commands?