# How do I conditionally run a task if another task was "created"?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that creates an AWS ELB and AWS ASG.

I only want to create the ASG if the ELB task CREATES (not updates) the ELB.

This is very similar to this question:
[Ansible - only run a series of tasks if a precondition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858251/ansible-only-run-a-series-of-tasks-if-a-precondition-is-met)
Whose solution is to register a variable with the result, and then use "when" statement, but in this case, the result of the ELB task is the same on creation AND update.

I don't want to create the ASG when the ELB is updated... I only want to create the ASG if the ELB was created, so I can't differentiate a create vs an update.

Thinking out loud, I could probably write a script to answer this question (ie query AWS to see when the ELB was created, for instance), but I'm hoping I could do it via Ansible.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get if you register the output and send it through debug with `register_var.__dict__`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the presence of ELB -> register $variable
2. Install/Update ELB
3. Create ASG depending of the output of $variable

Comment: But step 1 returns the same value in $variable  whether it is created OR updated.  I ended up using ansible to shell out a script that does this part for me.

Comment: Of course, you should not use a check, that yields the same output in both cases. This check should test on existence, so that it only yields "no existence" in the first run. For instance, check if a file is present or not.